# Creating bitwise operator in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, bit-manipulation

I want to get this query at last:

```
 select * from tableName where columnName & 2 = 2 and columnName & 4 = 4
```

How can I use LINQ to generate this script?

Comment: @Henk, in SQL you don't use double `==`. See SQL WHERE caluse information here and the operator section: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: @flip: But I think this is C# (LINQ), it pays to be clear about that.

Comment: @Henk, you don't do `select * from` in LINQ. It's `from x in`.

Comment: Right, I missed the `*`. Does SQL do bitwise-AND ?

Comment: Yes, bitwise AND (&), OR(|), XOR (^).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do bitwise operations in C# ( and in LINQ queries ) with either `&` or `|` depending on what bitwise operation you want.

```
var query =
            from row in context.tableName
            where (row.columnName & 2) == 2 && (row.columnName & 4) == 4
            select row
```

Comment: Will this run on the app server or the DB server, though?

Comment: @Justin, LINQ is evaluated to SQL in the end, so AFAIK it will run on the SQL Server. As long as you dont have `context.tableName.ToList()` instead, which would make it LINQ to Object instead of LINQ to EF / SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from r in context.tableName 
    where r.columnName & 2 == 2 and r.columnName & 4 == 4
    select r;
```